# hibernate one to many single direction

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hbm2ddl

I'm trying to make some hibernate stuff and create sql scripts automatically based on the hibernate annotations. Here is what I have:

Schedule class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ScheduleTableConsts.TABLE_NAME)
public class Schedule implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = ScheduleTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = ScheduleSlotTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
private List<ScheduleSlot> scheduleSlots;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = LessonTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
private List<Lesson> lessons;  

Constructors, getters, setters...
```

ScheduleSlot class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ScheduleSlotTableConsts.TABLE_NAME,
       uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {TimeSlotTableConsts.ID_COLUMN,
                                                             PlaceSlotTableConsts.ID_COLUMN})})
public class ScheduleSlot implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = ScheduleSlotTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = TimeSlotTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
private TimeSlot timeSlot;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = PlaceSlotTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
private PlaceSlot placeSlot;  

Constructors, getters, setters...
```

Lesson class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = LessonTableConsts.TABLE_NAME)
public class Lesson implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = LessonTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int            id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Professor> professors;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Course>    courses;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Group>     groups;

@Column(name = LessonTableConsts.LAB_COLUMN)
private boolean        lab;  

Constructors, getters, setters...
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to let schedule know about it's slots and lessons and not to let slots and lessons know about the schedule they are belong to. The code above seems to be ok, but when I'm trying to generate sql script (using maven and hibernate3-maven-plugin for that purposes) and run it the following happens:

1. It creates a SCHEDULE table with no pointers to SCHEDULESLOT or LESSON tables;
2. It creates SCHEDULESLOT and LESSON tables with no pointers to SCHEDULE table.

Could somebody, please, tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a thing you are forgetting to notice:

When using `@OneToMany` annotation, you cannot simply use `@JoinColumn`. However, on the other side, I mean `@ManyToOne`: you can use `@JoinColumn`.

It should be clear to you why this works this way, and not the other way around. (How can an entity keep so many IDs in just one column?)

So you have two options here:
1) Use a specific table to store relation between your `One` and `Many` entities. Something like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "SCHEDULE_SLOTS_MAPPING", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SCHEDULE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SCHEDULE_SLOT_ID"))
private List<ScheduleSlot> scheduleSlots;
```

2) Use the `@JoinColumn` on the `Many` side of the relationship: (e.g. your `ScheduleSlot` class)

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="SCHEDULE_ID")
private Schedule schedule;
```

Comment: In point 2), you should add a mappedBy clause to the @OneToMany in Schedule.
eg.

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy=ScheduleSlotTableConsts.ID_COLUMN)
    private List<ScheduleSlot> scheduleSlots;

Comment: It is not mandatory. If We want to have access from both sides, your claim is right. Otherwise, not at all. Despite that, it is not related to the question. Using `mappedBy` or not, does not change its validity.

Comment: Agreed. I assumed the poster wanted access to the list based on his original post.

Comment: oh, now I see. Thanks, @MatinKh! I'm not really experienced in hibernate and your answer made a lot of things clear to me. Thanks once again!